# Specify UTF-8 encoding for Hadoop jobs

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, internationalization, hadoop

In a Hadoop job I'm writing, I want UTF-8 encoded strings for my mappers/reducers. How do I specify UTF-8 as my system encoding? If I'm running code locally, I could just do `java -Dfile.encoding="UTF-8"`, but when I tried running `hadoop jap myjar.jar -Dfile.encoding="UTF-8"`, this didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Hadoop uses `UTF-8` encoding so you don't have to provide such options.
I assume you use `Text` for your keys/values. According to the [javadoc](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/index.html?org/apache/hadoop/io/Text.html): "This class stores text using standard UTF8 encoding"

Answer (score 4):

We found that the problem was that the mapper java processes didn't have  **-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8** .  We had to add that to "mapreduce.map.java.opts".  Same for "mapreduce.reduce.java.opts".

You can do it in the XML config files, as well as in Java like:

config.set("mapreduce.map.java.opts","-Xmx1843M -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8");

See http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/ClusterSetup.html for config details.